# How to access values from a List<> in the ViewModel for KendoUI Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

So I have the following ViewModel:

```
public class PecosViewModel
{
    public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
    public List<NPIModel> NpiList { get; set; }
}
```

On the cshtml page, I'm trying to do something like

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.ViewModels.PecosViewModel>()
        .Name("npi-grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.NpiList)
        })
    )
```

I can't access any of the properties of the NpiList (like FirstName or LastName).

I can do something really simple like this:

```
foreach (var item in Model.NpiList)
{
    <div>@item.NPI @String.Format("{0}, {1}", @item.ProviderLastName, @item.ProviderFirstName)</div>
}
```

But I'd really like to use the Kendo Grid.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining grid of type "PecosViewModel" whereas it should be of type "NPIModel". 
If you are passing ViewModel from action in the view then you can use below code:

```
@model Models.ViewModels.PecosViewModel

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.NpiList)
        .Name("npi-grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.NPI)
        })
    )
```

Comment: When I try this, Model turns red in Visual Studio with the note "The type or namespace name 'Model' could not be found. Cannot resolve the symbol Model'. What's weird is I can access Model.NpiList in my simple foreach script.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it looks like you are confusing things here.

The grid should be typed against the model you intend to use in this instance `NPIModel` rather than your view model.

the code you have there is binding the column to your list from your view model.

so rather than having:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.ViewModels.PecosViewModel>()
        .Name("npi-grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.NpiList)
        })
    )
```

you need to change it too:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.ViewModels.NPIModel>()
        .Name("npi-grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.FirstName)
        })
    )
```

**NB:** this assumes that both classes are in the same library if not replace accordingly.

then you should have access to the model properties to bind.

If you are then providing the results to the grid and not performing a read action then just send the existing list to the grid for that data to be bound:

e.g. **@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.NpiList)**

Comment: This got me much closer, but it shows the grid without any CSS (even though it's in the bundle) and for the column it just puts the Column Header and shows no data. Thank you! AJ

Comment: Also, for some reason I can't just do Model.NpiList. Model isn't available there, which is odd as I'm able to do that to generate a simple table of results.

Comment: Sometimes the intellisense doesn't pick up the model change until a reload of the solution if you change the model on screen. Otherwise just try referencing it with @Model.NpiList instead. If the css isn't being rendered then it may indicate an error when rendering the grid. Check the console (if you are sure the files are being included correctly)

Comment: I just end up getting the following error when I go to the page: The type or namespace name 'Model' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have the model declared at the top of the page (view)? as per @adhishspn post `@model Models.ViewModels.PecosViewModel'

Comment: Yep I have @model PecosViewModel. I'm able to do something like " foreach (var item in Model.vNPISearchResults)" and create a basic table. However, for this control it doesn't like having "Model" in there.